# Mixing named parameters with regular parameters

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

When I try to call a function such as this:

```
Columns.AddColumn("Caption", "U_Fam_ItmsGrpCod", 20, False)
```

But using named arguments like so:

```
Columns.AddColumn(Caption := "Caption", Field := "U_Fam_ItmsGrpCod", 20, False)
```

The compiler pops an error, expecting all parameters to be named. In other words, it forces me to either name ALL the paramenters, or name none of them. Is there a way to mix these two ways of using function parameters? For example, naming 2 parameters out of 6.

Additionally, is there a way to automatically name VB.NET parameters that is compatible with Visual Studio?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should take note for this explanation when mixing arguments by name and position as given in [Passing Arguments by Position and by Name in VB.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/passing-arguments-by-position-and-by-name#mixing-arguments-by-position-and-by-name):

> When you supply arguments by a mixture of position and name, the
>   positional arguments must all come first. **Once you supply an argument
>   by name, the remaining arguments must all be by name**.

Hence, this assignment is incorrect:

```
Columns.AddColumn(Caption := "Caption", Field := "U_Fam_ItmsGrpCod", 20, False)
```

The correct way is providing all arguments as named arguments from first place, like this example:

```
Columns.AddColumn(Caption := "Caption", Field := "U_Fam_ItmsGrpCod", OtherArgument1 := 20, OtherArgument2 := False)
```

Or you can omit named arguments for two first arguments and assign named arguments for remaining ones:

```
Columns.AddColumn("Caption", "U_Fam_ItmsGrpCod", OtherArgument1 := 20, OtherArgument2 := False)
```